# MarkLogic : Harmonize flow to skip writer

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

MarkLogic version : 9.0-6.2

We have a harmonize flow where we are preparing 'source' variable in content.sjs to be passed on to writer.sjs. I have a scenario where I should skip the writer (for example, if the document already exixts in final db and timestamp of staging doc is less than timestamp in final document, then I do not want to write to final)

Here is a code snippet in content.sjs

```
let source;
//logic to populate source
options.headers = source.envelope.headers;
return extractInstanceCustomer(source.envelope.instance);
```

We noticed that sometimes this is skipping the writer when source is empty. How ever, in some cases, writer is being called with empty source and hence the envelope is created with headers but instance is empty.

We tried below logic but still not seeing consistent behavior.

```
let source;
//logic to populate source

if (fn.empty(source)) {
}
else {
  options.headers = source.envelope.headers;
  return extractInstanceCustomer(source.envelope.instance);
}
```

What is the best way to skip writer when we do not want to write a document from staging, during harmonize flow.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best place to put this logic is really in the writer. There you have all data (headers, triples, instance, and attachments), and you have direct access to data in the Final database as well if you want to run checks against that too.

Alternative would be to put logic in the main of your harmonize flow.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense. How ever, we are more nervous about the inconsistent behavior of harmonization flow as we do see that it does not write to final DB (in some cases), though we do not have any checks in writer.sjs. There is definitely a reason behind it, but we are nervous that we are not fully aware of our code behavior

Comment: I would expect a harmonize to fail if you have a content script that returns nothing, which should be visible in traces..